# How to pass input and callback token to SQS lambda in AWS Step Functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have SQS FIFO queue attached the lambda function to process the queue. The SQS wrapped over the step function with callback to complete the execution. You can see the template file below.

```json
    {
      "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
      "StartAt": "SQS SendMessage",
      "States": {
        "SQS SendMessage": {
          "Type": "Task",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sqs:sendMessage.waitForTaskToken",
          "Parameters": {
            "MessageBody": {
              "input.$": "$",
              "token.$": "$$.Task.Token"
            },
            "QueueUrl": "https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxxx/myqueue.fifo",
            "MessageGroupId": "mygroupid"
          },
          "End": true
        }
      }
    }
```

I'm invoking the step function with the input value. Eg: `"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"`.
The step function sends the message to the SQS, But in the lambda function receives the empty body response below.

```json
    {
        "Records": [
            {
                "messageId": "f24bdd16-4234b-47534-a67a-f12234234356",
                "receiptHandle": "some random string",
                "body": null,  // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
                "attributes": {
                    "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
                    "SentTimestamp": "1667313159855",
                    "SequenceNumber": "49120530206362825178",
                    "MessageGroupId": "mygroupid",
                    "SenderId": "47X80CVTPC853VD6U5WSN:B9iwHdV1PkL1EbIDduFevS6KZ3YTrO0k",
                    "MessageDeduplicationId": "njijzrghtu1hgatdkwjub3j08i2fzuqs0wj5q7kl9mlxfkrad3xz35mt43kyq602",
                    "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1667313159855"
                },
                "messageAttributes": {},
                "md5OfBody": "kvzz7dtgoxv6kivo66260e3yn95igltj",
                "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
                "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:xxxxx:myqueue.fifo",
                "awsRegion": "eu-west-1"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am looking for the input value along with the token in the lambda function. I think MessageBody should be `string` instead of `object` and also append the token in the `MessageBody`.

Expected result is

```json
"body": "{\"foo\": \"bar\",\"token\": \"callbacktoken\"}",
```

or

```json
"body": {"payload": {"foo": "bar"}, "token": "callbacktoken"}
```

I have tried something like the below, but it doesn't work:

```json
"MessageBody.$":"States.JsonToString('{\"input.$\": \"$\", \"token.$\": \"$$$.Task.Token\"}', $)",
```

Am I approaching it correctly, or how to do it?

Comment: How are you starting the execution?  Console, CLI, SDK?  Try starting an execution with no input.  By the way, `body` will be a string in the happy case.

Comment: If you just change your sfn execution input to just `"foo"` does that still produce `"body": null` when you retrieve the message? I suspect there's a prob with encoding the stringified input twice because the `md5body` value doesn't look likes its equal to `null`

Comment: additionally, if you pause your lambda func, then pull the message directly off of the queue from the AWS console, do yo see the same results?